# Evince table of contents disappears after CTRL + F

Tags: 22.04, evince

When I view a pdf file in document viewer, I use the table of contents a lot. I also like to search terms with CTRL + F, but after I used that shortcut, the table of contents is no longer visible (the top left button also doesn't bring it back) and I have to restart the program for it to work again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to invoke the search option, even after finding what you are searching for, use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to the default layout with the default side panel listing the pages without the need to restart the program.

Evince (Document Viewer) version 3.36.10 on ubuntu 20.04 and v 42.3 on ubuntu 22.04